# how do you handle realtime feed updates?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time

I'm working on a site that is trying to handle realtime feed updates from its users' Facebook accounts.  I have the basic stuff in place: the app is subscribed to "feed", and the user's login asks for read_stream and offline_access (just in case) permissions.  My test users have logged into FB and granted those permissions, and, when one of those users adds (or removes) a status update, the callback specified in my site's subscription is pinged. So far, all's well.

Now -- as I understand it -- my callback has to call up to Facebook to get the user's feed, so that the callback can do whatever it's going to do with it.  That's where I'm having problems -- finding the right access token to retrieve the feed:

- I've tried doing this with the app's access token.  This token is able to retrieve friend information (also included in the app's subscription and user permissions), but it won't get me the feed.
- I've tried all sorts of ways to get the user's access token from inside the callback, but nothing is working. I'm guessing this is because it's not "logged into Facebook" the way that a user in a browser can be, but whatever.  Bottom line is I haven't found a way to get this token.

(BTW, if I cheat -- get an access token for the user from Graph API Explorer and hard-code it into the callback, the callback works properly.  This is no real solution, of course, but it at least establishes that the rest of my code is working.)

So how does this work?  Can the app access token be made to work somehow?  Is there in fact a way for the callback to get an access token for an arbitrary authorized user?  There's gotta be a way to do this, or there would be no point for realtime feed notifications.  Any clues out there?  This is SERIOUSLY kicking my butt...  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution, perhaps:  When the user logs in, I snag their offline_access-enabled access token and save it in the app with the rest of the user's data. Then when I get notified of an update to that user's feed, I can pull the token from the database and pass it over to FB as the token part of the /feed... call. And, it works. There is no doubt some error handling to be done, but I am currently bouncing back and forth between thinking that (a) this is exactly the right way to handle this and (b) it's a terrible hack that is just asking for trouble. I guess I'll see which of these is the case...

Comment: Yes, if you have an access_token, it normally expires in 1-2 hours I think. You need offline_access if you need to use that token longer.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into this. Instead of taking permission for offline access, facebook now gives short-lived access tokens (2 hours) when the user logs in. These can be exchanged with long-lived access tokens (2 months). Check out this article on how to go about it.

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 1):

Ask for offline_access (as you do) and store the access token. This is exactly why offline_access and access tokens are there, to make requests to facebook in the name of that user. (a) is the right way to go. (a) is the way I do it. 
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

When the user is authenticated via OAuth Facebook returns an access-token, but it is valid for few hours. The validity of this token comes with it as token-expiry.
However, this token can be exchanged with a new extended token which is valid for around 60 days. User the following code to get new-token:

URL url=new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id="+appId+"&client_secret="+clientSecretId+"&fb_exchange_token="+fb_exchange_token;

InputStream Istream=url.openConnection().getInputStream();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Istream));

String new_token= br.readLine();

Hope it helps!!